# Finding a closed formula for calculating $\frac{d^n}{{dx}^n}f\left(x\right)=\frac{d^n}{{dx}^n}e^{x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

For reasons I can't even remember, the other day I wanted to find out if there was a **closed formula for calculating the $n$-th derivative $\frac{d^n}{{dx}^n}f\left(x\right)=\frac{d^n}{{dx}^n}e^{x^2}$ for the function $f\left(x\right)=e^{x^2}$**. Where I ended up after some trial and error is the formula $$\frac{d^n}{{dx}^n}e^{x^2}=c_n\left(\sum_{0 \leq i \leq \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} {p_i x^{n-2i}}\right)e^{x^2}=c_n\left(c_{n-1}x^n + \sum_{1 \leq i \leq \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} {p_i x^{n-2i}}\right)e^{x^2},$$ with $c_n=2^{n-\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$.

The $p_{i \geq1}$ turn out to be as follows:

| $n$ | $p_{i=1}$ | $p_{i=2}$ | $p_{i=3}$ | $p_{i=4}$ | $...$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | – | – | – | – | $...$ |
| 1 | – | – | – | – | $...$ |
| 2 | 1 | – | – | – | $...$ |
| 3 | 3 | – | – | – | $...$ |
| 4 | 12 | 3 | – | – | $...$ |
| 5 | 20 | 15 | – | – | $...$ |
| 6 | 60 | 90 | 15 | – | $...$ |
| 7 | 84 | 210 | 105 | – | $...$ |
| 8 | 224 | 840 | 840 | 105 | $...$ |
| 9 | 288 | 1512 | 2520 | 945 | $...$ |
| $...$ | $...$ | $...$ | $...$ | $...$ | $...$ |

I have not yet understood the rule behind the $p_i$ sequences $$p_{i=1}:\left(1,3,12,20,60,84,224,288,...\right),$$

$$p_{i=2}:\left(3,15,90,210,840,1512,...\right),$$

$$p_{i=3}:\left(15,105,840,2520,...\right),$$

$$p_{i=4}:\left(105,945,...\right),$$

$$...$$ I suspect it has something to do with **binomial coefficients**, since the coefficients $p_i$ arise from multiplying binomials during the derivation. One regularity I've noticed so far is that starting at $p_{i=2}$, the first values always correspond to the second ones of the previous $p$ sequence.

Do any of you have an idea **how I can formalize the coefficients $p_i$ and the timing of their occurrence and integrate them into the above closed formula?** Or do you know if there even already exists a known solution to the problem, namely finding a closed formula to calculate the $n$-th derivative $\frac{d^n}{{dx}^n}f\left(x\right)=\frac{d^n}{{dx}^n}e^{x^2}$?

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Look up Hermite polynomials, this is related to that

Comment: **Hint** Use the [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Using Wolfram Alpha we find for small values of $n$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}e^{x^2}&=2x^2e^{x^{2}}\\
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{x^2}&=2\left(2x^2+1\right)e^{x^{2}}\\
\frac{d^3}{dx^3}e^{x^2}&=4\left(2x^3+3x\right)e^{x^{2}}\tag{1}\\
\frac{d^4}{dx^4}e^{x^2}&=4\left(4x^4+12x^2+3\right)e^{x^{2}}\\
\end{align*}

Another expression besides Faa di Brunos formula is stated as identity (3.56) in H.W. Gould's *[Tables of Combinatorial Identities, Vol. I](https://web.archive.org/web/20180218233224/http://www.math.wvu.edu/%7Egould/Vol.1.PDF)* and called:

> **Hoppe Form of Generalized Chain Rule**
>
> Let $D_x$ represent differentiation with respect to $x$ and $y=y(x)$. Hence $D^n_x g(y)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$. The following holds true
> \begin{align*}
> D_x^n g(y)=\sum_{k=0}^nD_y^kg(y)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}y^{k-j}D_x^ny^j
> \end{align*}

In the special case
\begin{align*}
g(y(x))=e^{y(x)}=e^{x^{2}}
\end{align*}
we have $$D_y^kg(y)=D_y^k e^y=e^y$$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
D_x^ne^y=e^y\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}y^{k-j}D_x^ny^j\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> With $y=y(x)=x^2$ we obtain from (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{D_x^ne^{x^2}}&=e^{x^2}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}x^{2(k-j)}D_x^nx^{2j}\tag{3.1}\\
> &=e^{x^2}\sum_{k=\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}x^{2(k-j)}D_x^nx^{2j}\tag{3.2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=e^{x^2}\sum_{k=\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}(2j)^{\underline{n}}x^{2k-n}}\tag{3.3}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we apply Hoppe's formula with $y=y(x)=x^2$.
- In (3.2) we observe that we differentiate $x^{2j}$ $n$ times. This implies that terms with indices $k,j< \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ vanish.
- In (3.3) we calculate $D_x^nx^{2j}$ using the *[falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)* notation $(2j)^{\underline{n}}=(2j)(2j-1)\cdots(2j-n+1)$.

> Let's look at a small example in order to see formula (3.3) in action.
>
> **Example: $n=3$** We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> e^{x^2}&\sum_{k=2}^{3}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=2}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}(2j)(2j-1)(2j-2)x^{2k-3}\\
> &=4e^{x^2}\sum_{k=2}^{3}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=2}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}j(j-1)(2j-1)x^{2k-3}\\
> &=4e^{x^2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{j=2}^2(-1)^j\binom{2}{j}j(j-1)(2j-1)\right)\right)x\\
> &\qquad+4e^{x^2}\left(\frac{(-1)}{6}\left(\sum_{j=2}^3(-1)^j\binom{3}{j}j(j-1)(2j-1)\right)\right)x^3\\
> &=4e^{x^2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\binom{2}{2}\cdot 6\right)x
> +4e^{x^2}\left(-\frac{1}{6}\binom{3}{2}\cdot 6+\frac{1}{6}\binom{3}{3}\cdot 30\right)x^3\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=4e^{x^2}\left(2x^3+3x\right)}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (1).